# While loop not saving results

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a while for a random number of occurence "y". However the while loop does not show "result" or display anything when prompted. I only get the same random numbers generated initially as my result. I want to add a second column to my result vector that shows the calculation of each X values under the conditions in the loop, for some reason the second column is not being saved. and I am just getting a column vector "X".

```
y = round(rand*10);

x = randi([-5,5],1,y);
X = x';
result=[X];

while isempty(result)==1
    disp('Nothing')

    if result > 2
        disp('A')
        result=[result,result+5];
    else
        disp('B')
        result=[result,result*0];
    end
end
```

Comment: you know semi colons without output right?

Comment: yes, that is just me supressing the output. in the comand prompt I am not getting a two column vector, instead I am just getting back the same random X values as a column vector, however I need that, but with an addition column with the results.

Comment: I don't know about MatLab but `X = x';` has a single quote on it.

Comment: the single quote is to turn a column vector into a row vector and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is due to your `while` condition.  Specifically, take a look at the logic inside your `while` statement:

```
while isempty(result)==1
```

The `while` loop will only execute **if `result` is empty**.  This is not the case, as `result = X` at the beginning of your code.  As such, your `while` loop never executes.

---

Given your explanation in your comment below, you wish to generate a random number, and every time you do this, you want to check if the result is greater than 2 or not.  If it is, add 5 to this element and add this as an element to a new column.  If not, simply replace this with 0.

I would suggest you use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop because you probably want the matrix to stop growing after a certain point.

Therefore, do something like this instead:

```
y = round(rand*10);
result = [];
x = randi([-5,5],1,y);

for idx = 1 : y
    if x(idx) > 2
        result = [result [x(idx); x(idx)+5]];
    else
        result = [result [x(idx); 0]];
    end
end
```

What you're doing first is you are determining a random number that defines the limit of how many random numbers you want to generate.  We then declare an empty array that will store our result.  After, we generate our random numbers, then we use a `for` loop to cycle through every element of `x` and check to see what their value is.  If the value is `> 2`, then we add this number to our 2D matrix where its value is added by 5 to a new column.  If not, we just set this value to 0.

When I did a run with this, this is what I got for `result`:

```
result =

     5     2    -5     4     5
    10     0     0     9    10
```

However, you can easily do this **without** a `for` loop and do it completely vectorized.  You could simply replace the above code with:

```
y = round(rand*10);
x = randi([-5,5],1,y);

%// NEW
result = [x; zeros(1,y)];
ind = x > 2;
result(2,ind) = result(1,ind) + 5;
```

What the above code does is that we initialize `result` to be the 2D array already, where the first row consists of those numbers randomly generated, and the second row has a bunch of zeroes.  We search for any randomly generated values that are `> 2`, then use these positions to update the second row, where we take those values that satisfy this condition and add 5 to each value.  We then store the results in the second row.  If you run the above code, you should be able to produce the same results.

Comment: To tell the truth, this is technically the first time I am using while loop, I always use for loops in matlab. But I see what you are saying, it will only execute while the result is empty. The reason for using the while loop is that the number of occurence "Y" would be random. I will just do a for loop like this `for i=1:Y`. I will not be using anymore while loops for now esp in complex situtation like this.

Comment: @Crisp - Gotcha.  I am actually not sure what your code is doing.  Can you provide a bit more background as to what the purpose is?  I have some questions about how it's supposed to work (see my edits).  I'd like you to walk away with code that works to your specs.

Comment: Basically I generate some random numbers in a column vector form (one column) that is the result vector. After that if any element in my column vector is greater than 2, I add a 5 to it. if the result is less than or equal to two it will be a zero. so a second column will be created with the results. eg 'result = [-4 -5 3]`, after the loop the result vector will have 'result = [-4 -5 3; 0 0 8]`. so -4 and -5 becomes 0 because they are less than or equal to 2, but you add a 5 to 3 because 3 is greater than 2.

Comment: @Crisp - You can easily do that in 4 lines of code.  Is it mandatory to use a `while` loop?  Either way, let me edit my answer for you.

Comment: Lol I know, but I was trying to do it with a while loop in the event of not knowing the number of times of times there will be a loop. that is why i used `y = round(rand*10)` to generate a number of random occurence. then use `x = randi([-5,5],1,y)`. What I am trying to do is to model the amount of cars that pass somone while driving, and I assumed that a while loop was the way to go since based on the model the amount that passes is not known. I think it can be done with a for loop though.

Comment: and it is not mandatory, but I just wanted to create a feel of random occurence with the while loop.

Comment: @Crisp - Gotcha :).  Well, I did update my answer though.  Have a look!

Comment: perfect, one more question, why are while loops so limited? they have a very limited feel to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69782/discussion-between-crisp-and-rayryeng).

Comment: @Crisp - oh not necessarily!  `while` loops are used when you **can't** predict when behaviour is supposed to end.  For example, you could have a `while` loop while **waiting** for something to happen... and it won't break out **until it does**.  `for` loops are used when you know something is going to happen a **set amount of times**.

Comment: @Crisp - Oops!  Sorry about that.  Go back to our discussion in chat.  Had a bit of an emergency.  Take care!